# Ubuntu reduce/increase the number of cores used on a per demand base

Tags: ubuntu, dell-poweredge, cpu-usage, ubuntu-16.04, ipmi

I would like to ask for best practices how to manage on demand base the number of cores in use of a Dell PowerEdge 1950 Gen II running Ubuntu 16.04 lts.

The PowerEdge 1950 has two quad core Intel Xeon X5363 processors, power on demand enabled in BIOS and fully supports IPMI.

Here under are the details and capabilities of the X5365

```
  *-cpu:0
       description: CPU
       product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5365  @ 3.00GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 400
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5365  @ 3.00GHz
       slot: CPU1
       size: 2GHz
       capacity: 3600MHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 1333MHz
       capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm cpufreq
       configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
  *-cpu:1
       description: CPU
       product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5365  @ 3.00GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 401
       bus info: cpu@1
       version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5365  @ 3.00GHz
       slot: CPU2
       size: 2GHz
       capacity: 3600MHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 1333MHz
       capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm cpufreq
       configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
```

This is detailed info of the X5365 CPUs:

```
user@server:~$ sudo cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 2.00 GHz - 3.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.00 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.33 GHz, 2.00 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 2.00 GHz and 3.00 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.00 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 3.00 GHz:44.02%, 2.67 GHz:0.32%, 2.33 GHz:0.34%, 2.00 GHz:55.33%  (71)
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 2.00 GHz - 3.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.00 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.33 GHz, 2.00 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 2.00 GHz and 3.00 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 3.00 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 3.00 GHz:38.36%, 2.67 GHz:0.03%, 2.33 GHz:1.47%, 2.00 GHz:60.15%  (92)
analyzing CPU 2:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 2
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 2
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 2.00 GHz - 3.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.00 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.33 GHz, 2.00 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 2.00 GHz and 3.00 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.00 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 3.00 GHz:46.97%, 2.67 GHz:1.24%, 2.33 GHz:1.75%, 2.00 GHz:50.04%  (158)
analyzing CPU 3:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 3
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 2.00 GHz - 3.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.00 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.33 GHz, 2.00 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 2.00 GHz and 3.00 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.00 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 3.00 GHz:38.12%, 2.67 GHz:0.04%, 2.33 GHz:0.36%, 2.00 GHz:61.47%  (67)
analyzing CPU 4:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 4
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 4
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 2.00 GHz - 3.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.00 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.33 GHz, 2.00 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 2.00 GHz and 3.00 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.00 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 3.00 GHz:47.15%, 2.67 GHz:2.25%, 2.33 GHz:0.44%, 2.00 GHz:50.16%  (100)
analyzing CPU 5:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 5
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 5
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 2.00 GHz - 3.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.00 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.33 GHz, 2.00 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 2.00 GHz and 3.00 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.00 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 3.00 GHz:41.84%, 2.67 GHz:0.35%, 2.33 GHz:0.42%, 2.00 GHz:57.39%  (68)
analyzing CPU 6:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 6
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 6
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 2.00 GHz - 3.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.00 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.33 GHz, 2.00 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 2.00 GHz and 3.00 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.00 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 3.00 GHz:52.61%, 2.67 GHz:0.47%, 2.33 GHz:3.11%, 2.00 GHz:43.81%  (158)
analyzing CPU 7:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 7
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 7
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 2.00 GHz - 3.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.00 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.33 GHz, 2.00 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 2.00 GHz and 3.00 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.00 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 3.00 GHz:51.61%, 2.67 GHz:0.48%, 2.33 GHz:0.38%, 2.00 GHz:47.53%  (103)
```

How can I reduce/increase the number of cores on a per demand base? Tried cpufrequtils but have not succeeded.

Comment: I don't think this is possible at the physical level. Maybe use a VM and create virtual CPUs. Even then, you'll have to restart the guest